# Usage of "Only when X will Y and then only when Z"

Tags: word-usage

This sentence:

> Only when input goes to logic 1 (s) will the FSM move from state s<sub>0</sub> to s<sub>1</sub>, and then only when a clock pulse arrives.

I have read in a book related to digital logic.

I know  the meaning of this sentence: when the input goes to logic 1 **and afterwards** a clock pulse arrives, **then** the FSM moves from state s<sub>0</sub> to s<sub>1</sub>.

Can you just explain the usage of the *"only when ... will the ... and then only when"* structure.

Comment: Recommending migration to [ell.se]

Comment: "only when .. will the ... and then only" is not a special "structure." Learn the expression *only when* (not 'then only') -- parse that part as "(and then) (only when) (a clock pulse arrives.) HTH.

Comment: It's *terrible* English (probably written by someone with technical skills, not writing skills). At the very least it should be re-sequenced to *the FSM moves from state s0 to s1 only if a clock pulse arrives when inputs are logic 1* (that first caveat now placed last in my version is a total mess, and doesn't look like any English I recognise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just poorly worded. If this were about different things, it would even be ambiguous in a very confusing way. As you are aware, this is the basic meaning of the sentence:

- When the FSM is in state s0, it only moves to state s1 if the input goes to logic 1 and a clock pulse arrives.

The author decided to present the wiring of the input as the main condition and add the clock pulse condition like an afterthought. (Probably because this will happen anyway, sooner or later.)

- Only when the input goes to logic 1 will the FSM move from state s0 to s1, and even then only when a clock pulse arrives. (This construction is commonly used without *even*, but here that word is necessary to prevent the ambiguity described below.)

Presumably clock pulses are generally what makes this FSM change its state. I guess the author didn't like this version because it sounds as if a clock pulse were an unlikely event. So they dropped *even*.

- Only when the input goes to logic 1 will the FSM move from state s0 to s1, and then only when a clock pulse arrives.

The result is a very unusual construction, but one that closely mirrors the events. Someone or some event wires the input to logic 1, which is the key condition for moving to s1. And then, when a clock pulse arrives, it actually happens.

Now here is the theoretical ambiguity. To someone with no or confused knowledge about FSMs (finite state machines), it's conceivable that the following meaning is intended:

- The FSM only moves from state s0 to s1 if the input goes to logic 1. After this has happened (immediately afterwards? even much later?), the FSM only moves to s1 again, when a clock pulse arrives.

In such a book there is probably no need to worry about this kind of misunderstanding, but it's still poor style that this alternative reading is possible for such a convoluted sentence.

Comment: "When the FSM is in state s0, it only moves to state s1 if the input goes to logic 1 and a clock pulse arrives." Will this sentence convey the meaning that the events 'input goes to logic 1' and clock pulse are sequential events.

Comment: I was thinking of "the input goes to logic 1" as the input being wired to logic 1. Is this actually about an individual piece of input moving to logic 1? Then my analysis isn't correct. Maybe you can also fix the confusing typo in your quotation: "inputs goes". I am note entirely sure whether this is supposed to be singular or plural.